# Cannot open sample Employee.gdb from FireDac Explorer

Tags: delphi, firedac, delphi-10.2-tokyo

If I open the FireDAC Explorer in Delphi Tokyo 10.2.1 and click the + sign in front of the employee database, it says it cannot find the file:

[image]

> [FireDAC][Phys][IB]I/O error during "CreateFile (open)" operation for file ":localhost:C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Samples\data\employee.gdb"
>   Error while trying to open file

Note the colon in front of *localhost*, I suspect that is the reason.

The entry in `FDConnectionsDef.ini` is:

```
[EMPLOYEE]
DriverID=IB
Protocol=TCPIP
Database=localhost:C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Samples\data\employee.gdb
User_Name=sysdba
Password=masterkey
CharacterSet=
ExtendedMetadata=True
```

- File `C:\Users\Public\Documents\Embarcadero\Studio\19.0\Samples\data\employee.gdb` exists. That is also the string in the value column, you can't see that in the screenshot.
- The same error occurs trying to connect from one of their sample programs

How can I get this to work?

Comment: Sorry for what may be a stupid q, but can you open Employee.Gdb from  IBConsole.Exe?

Comment: Yes I can open it, but I then get a subsequent error since I have only FireBird and not InterBase installed on my machine (DB version is 15.0, but supported is max 11.2). I left that out of the question to not confuse things.

Comment: A similar problem caused me hours of head-scratching.  I'm not sure this will work for you but it only takes a couple of minutes to try:  stop the Firebird service and start the Interbase one.  Then try IBConsole and the FireDAC Explorer again.

Comment: Works perfectly over here. On the other hand, I actually have InterBase installed.

Comment: @MartynA You are my hero!!!! It worked. I had to turn off firebird and turn on interbase services.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you let the Firebird installer create InterBase compatible client library gds32.dll, which is now used for connecting to Interbase database when using IB driver.

Answer (score 0):

@MartynA comments helped me to solve the issue. I'll describe it in detail here in case it is going to be helpful for someone else.

I needed to do that:

1. Stop Firebird services
2. Start Interbase services

To start/stop a service you need to:

1. Go to Control Panel
2. Search for Administrative Tools and click on it
3. Tap Services
4. Then you will find a screen with the services
5. To start/stop a service you just need to click on check start/stop on the left buttons